# Insertable object in a class with @IdClass annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, java-persistence-api

Is it possible to do a cascade save in Section.class?
I create Section object and add new questions without id.
When I try save it I get error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table
>   "question_to_section" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_2br9f09ok965403a9rv5y2n10"   Details: Key (question_id)=(0) is not
>   present in table "question".

I also tried to use @Embedded annotation, but unsuccessfully.

Section class:

```
@Table(name = "section")
@Entity(name = "section")
public class Section implements Serializable{   

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id",    unique = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty
    long id;    

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "section")
    Set<QuestionToSection> questions = new HashSet<QuestionToSection>(0);
    ...
}
```

Question To Section class

```
@Entity(name = "question_to_section")
@Table(name = "question_to_section")
@IdClass(QuestionSectionId.class)
public class QuestionToSection implements Serializable {

    @Id
    long sectionId;

    @Id
    long questionId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sectionId", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    Section section;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn(name = "questionId", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
    Question question;
    ...
}
```

QuestionSectionId

```
public class QuestionSectionId implements Serializable {

    long questionId;
    long sectionId; 

}
```

Comment: It seems like the true relationship here is many-to-many between `Question`s and `Section`s.  What's the point of interposing the `QuestionToSection` entity?

Comment: your problem is in the relation with updatable=false, insertable=false, to make your M-M you are not allowing cascade insertion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary for every table in your database to be mapped to an entity.  In particular, pure join tables are usually better *not* mapped as entities.  For a many-to-many relationship, for example:

```
@Table(name = "section")
public class Section implements Serializable{   

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty
    long id;    

    // Note: probably do not want to cascade REMOVE operations
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH},
        mappedBy = "sections")
    @JoinTable(
        name = "question_to_section"
        joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name="sectionId", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
            @JoinColumn(name="questionId", referencedColumnName="ID")
    )
    Set<Question> questions = new HashSet<Question>(0);
    ...
}
```

That presumes a bidirectional relationship, with corresponding annotations in entity `Question`; for unidirectional, remove the `mappedBy` attribute of the `ManyToMany`.  Either way, this relieves you of managing the `question_to_entity` table directly, and reduces the number of discrete entities in the system.

---

If, on the other hand, you need a *bona fide* `QuestionToSection` weak entity -- *i.e.* if instances have properties other than question and section they associate -- then you indeed have a problem with cascading persistence.  What you're trying to do maps more than one entity property to the same column in your DB, thus affording opportunities for inconsistency.

And there *is* an inconsistency if one or both of the `Question` and `Section` entities involved is new, so that it does not yet have an ID.  JPA has no way to know that it's supposed to set `QuestionToSection`'s id fields from the IDs of the associated `Question` and `Section` entities.  When they receive their autogenerated IDs, the `QuestionToSection` entities associated with them will become inconsistent.

It is conceivable that you could work around the problem by setting `@Access(AccessType = PROPERTY)` on `QuestionToSection`, and playing games with the persistent property accessor methods, but this is kinda nasty.  If you do need a weak entity here then it's probably better to not try to cascade `PERSIST` operations to it, though you could cascade other operations.  And in fact, in this case you probably do want to cascade `REMOVE` operations *to* the weak entity, but not *from* it to the other associated entities.

Comment: @JohnBolliner thank you for your response. I need to add few extra properties for QuestionToSection table so I can't use simple many-to-many relationship.I think I need to change the structure of the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `insertable = false` from both `@JoinColumn` in the class `QuestionToSection`. You are overring the cascade insert doing this, so the JPA wont insert if they dont exist. Just remove the insertable from the annotation and that sould resolve your problem.

Comment: I tried to remove `insertable = false` but hibernate returns `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.norbsoft.beviado.models.article.QuestionToSection column: question_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`